# Sharepoint 2010 Top link bar

Tags: sharepoint-server

When I create a sub-site it is automatically creating a link the top link bar of the main site.  I don't want a link to be created when I create a new subsite.  Is it possible to change this?

Answer (score 2):

when you create a subsite at that time you have this option wheter you want to add this site in top Link bar or not.

- Site actions > New Site on this page click on more optins
  [image]
- On this screen after entering the Title, Descrption and if you scroll down you will see the options for navigation. **Display the Site on the top link Bar of Parent Site**, this option is **yes by default**. once you select No, then it will not appear in top link bar.
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

you can navigate to Site Actions -> Look and Feel Section -> Navigation and set the links you want to see and hide using Global Navigation
[image]

[image]